# Sound Design in Martha Marcy May Marlene

Tags: sound-design, podcasts, studies

**Questions should be in by end of day Saturday July 14th******

Hello All

Some of you may know of the Sound Design focused podcast called The Tonebenders ( http://www.tonebenders.net/ ) that myself, along with Rene Coronado and Dustin Camillari have been putting out for the last while.  We have something planned for our next episode and I was hoping to get a bit of help from the sound community to pull it off.

We are going to do a case study of the sound design in the film "Martha Marcy May Marlene" and we have lined up the film's sound designer, Coll Anderson, to take part.  It would be great if anyone has seen the film to join in the discussion by sending us questions you may have on the film or Coll's career in general.  If you have not seen Martha Mary May Marlene it is worth a look as it is a unique and engrossing film.  It is widely available via standard streaming and online rental outlets.

If you are interested in joining in on the conversation please feel free to leave questions  for Coll Anderson here or send us an email through info-at-tonebenders-dot-net

Here is a link to the film's trailer
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERREgOobLOs

Here is Coll Anderson's IMDB page if you are not familiar with his background:
http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0026541/

Finally here is a quick post from Coll's blog on his experience working on the film:
http://www.casoundinc.com/wp/?p=29

If interested please take part and send in questions, hopefully this can be the start of many case studies to be featured on the podcast.  Also if you know of another film you think we should disect in the future let us know.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing that would be perfect for a Sound Design blog, going forwards, but doesn't fit the Stack Exchange Q&A model.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is very localised and doesn't fit the SE Q&A model.

Answer (score 0):

I loved the sound post for that film. It seemed really well integrated, and added so much to the mood, i felt.

Two things that i liked about the sound design were the ambiguous transitions between scenes/times/places; and the use of sound POV to portray character headspace. It seems like the picture was cut with consideration for sound; i'd be keen to know whether there was much interaction between sound and picture post to achieve this.

Also, i'm a big fan of sound design that, in any other context would seem totally wrong, but works perfectly in the context in which its placed. Like the 2 things i mentioned before: ambiguous aural scene changes would confuse a lot of people, but added so much to the mood in this film; and sound POV can be hard to pull off. I'd like to know if Coll has any philosophies or approaches for/to finding these sound opportunities and making them work.

Hopefully that all makes sense. It feels a bit convoluted, so just let me know if i should clarify anything.

Thanks for doing this!

Comment: Thanks Shaun!!  Looking forward to hearing Coll's responses!

Answer (score 0):

I would love to hear everything about dialogue editing, if Anderson worked on those. What Microphone was used, what Compressor and so on. I really love the sound of the dialogues and I am very interested in getting the same result.

Thx